# How to Incorporate and Forecast Lagged Time-Series Variables in a Python Regression Model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, statsmodels

I'm trying to figure out how to incorporate lagged dependent variables into statsmodel or scikitlearn to forecast time series with AR terms but cannot seem to find a solution.

The general linear equation looks something like this:

y = B1*y(t-1) + B2*x1(t) + B3*x2(t-3) + e

I know I can use pd.Series.shift(t) to create lagged variables and then add it to be included in the model and generate parameters, but how can I get a prediction when the code does not know which variable is a lagged dependent variable?

In SAS's Proc Autoreg, you can designate which variable is a lagged dependent variable and will forecast accordingly, but it seems like there are no options like that in Python.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already mentioned `statsmodels` in your tags you may want to take a look at [statsmodels - ARIMA](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.html), i.e.:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

model = ARIMA(endog=t, order=(2, 0, 0))  # p=2, d=0, q=0 for AR(2)
fit = model.fit()
fit.summary()
```

But like you mentioned, you could create new variables manually the way you described (I used some random data):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/a10.csv', parse_dates=['date'])
df['random_variable'] = np.random.randint(0, 10, len(df))
df['y'] = np.random.rand(len(df))
df.index = df['date']
df = df[['y', 'value', 'random_variable']]
df.columns = ['y', 'x1', 'x2']

shifts = 3

for variable in df.columns.values:
    for t in range(1, shifts + 1):
        df[f'{variable} AR({t})'] = df.shift(t)[variable]

df = df.dropna()
```

```
>>> df.head()
                   y        x1  x2    ...     x2 AR(1)  x2 AR(2)  x2 AR(3)
date                                  ...                                 
1991-10-01  0.715115  3.611003   7    ...          5.0       7.0       7.0
1991-11-01  0.202662  3.565869   3    ...          7.0       5.0       7.0
1991-12-01  0.121624  4.306371   7    ...          3.0       7.0       5.0
1992-01-01  0.043412  5.088335   6    ...          7.0       3.0       7.0
1992-02-01  0.853334  2.814520   2    ...          6.0       7.0       3.0
[5 rows x 12 columns]
```

I'm using the model you describe in your post:

```
model = sm.OLS(df['y'], df[['y AR(1)', 'x1', 'x2 AR(3)']])
fit = model.fit()
```

```
>>> fit.summary()
<class 'statsmodels.iolib.summary.Summary'>
"""
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.696
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.691
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     150.8
Date:                Tue, 08 Oct 2019   Prob (F-statistic):           6.93e-51
Time:                        17:51:20   Log-Likelihood:                -53.357
No. Observations:                 201   AIC:                             112.7
Df Residuals:                     198   BIC:                             122.6
Df Model:                           3                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
y AR(1)        0.2972      0.072      4.142      0.000       0.156       0.439
x1             0.0211      0.003      6.261      0.000       0.014       0.028
x2 AR(3)       0.0161      0.007      2.264      0.025       0.002       0.030
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        2.115   Durbin-Watson:                   2.277
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.347   Jarque-Bera (JB):                1.712
Skew:                           0.064   Prob(JB):                        0.425
Kurtosis:                       2.567   Cond. No.                         41.5
==============================================================================
Warnings:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
"""
```

Hope this helps you getting started.

Comment: I understand you can fit the model using lagged variable as an exogenous variable, but how can you predict out of sample data? For example, if the model is fit up until 2019, how can you predict 2020+ when the fitted model doesn't know how to lag each predicted y iteratively? 2020 will get predicted since y(t-1) is 2019 but when you are trying to predict 2021, y(t-1) will be 2020, which will be null. Do you have to iteratively predict the next predicted value and replace the lag value into t+1?

Comment: Yes - that is exactly what you would have to do.

Comment: how could i do that ? @ds254